# how to trim leading 0, not at beginning of alphanumeric string with `sed`

Tags: sed, trim, leading-zero

given examples:

```
A10
A01
A1
B09
B80
C11
```

how to trim leading zero's retaining alphabet, using `sed`?

expected results from source examples:

```
A10
A1
A1
B9
B80
C11
```

^[0] does not apply here because it's not beginning of string. matching [A-Z][0] could work, but need result to retain the [A-Z] and i don't know how to do so.

Comment: please update the question with a few examples of the code you've attempted along the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: sorry no examples, have ~100 bash_history listings and do not remember what was bad/close/not-close.  only the solution is important to me now.

Answer (score 2):

With *sed* substitution:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Z])0?([0-9]+)/\1\2/' test.txt
```

- `0?` - matches optional zero between captured groups

---

```
A10
A1
A1
B9
B80
C11
```

Comment: thank you to both @RomanPerekhrest and @markalex -- these both suit my needs. believing the `0?` version more complete. and moreover, the `\1\2` a specific and necessary part that i was missing in my attempts.